# Overwriting of Excel files keeps occurring; xlsx; python

Tags: excel, python-2.7, xlsx, overwrite

I have tried searching but could not find one similar to worksheet.xslx which I'm using. I do not have panda modules in my program.

Aim: E.g. There's 5 files. Extract some values from file 1 and put into column 1. Extract some values from file 2 and put into column 2, etc.

Problem: The codes I used are as shown below. The latest file that my program is running would keep overwriting the worksheet and the earlier files were wiped off. (I.e. the excel files in the end only shows column 5. Column 1-4 is empty.)
Kindly advice on what I should do. Thank you!

Codes:

```
import csv
import os
import py2exe
from os import rename, listdir
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlwt import Workbook
import xlrd
import xlwt
import py2exe
import xlsxwriter
from os.path import basename


filesnum=()
wb=Workbook()

class Window:

 def process_csv(self):
    global index
    global abc
    abc = 0

    direct=self.filename2 #assuming directory is correct

    filesname = "C:\file1" "C:\file2", "etc etc")): #ignore the errors made here as my original codes is correct for this part
    for b in range (len(filesname)):
        abc+=1
        if "123456" in open(filesnum[b]).read():
            wantedarray=list()
            count = 0
            workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(direct + "/newbie.xlsx")
            worksheet=workbook.add_worksheet("newbie")

            for line in copyid:
                if "abcde" in line: 
                    wantedno=line[:8]
                    arrayfound.append(wantedno) #take out the number
                elif "ending" in line:
                    break  
                else:
                    continue        
            for index, value in enumerate(arrayfound):
                worksheet.write(index+2, abc, value)
            workbook.close()
        else:
            continue

root = Tk()
window=Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've downloaded and used openpyxl to solve this.

```
wb.save(direct + "/newbie.xlsx")
```